# How to turn off SMS Bubble on Karbonn Titanium Octane Plus running KitKat 4.4.2?

Tags: sms

I've bought a new Phone which has KitKat 4.4.2 (Karbonn Titanium Octane Plus) with kernel version 3.4.67.

It has a very annoying feature of SMS Bubble that pops up when there is any message and the most annoying feature is that it doesn't gets away till you read the message.

How to turn off this feature?

Comment: What is your default messaging app? . Try disabling the app and install different app from play store. Is it only for text messages ? You can also try going to the setting of the messaging app and find the option to disable pop up if there is any

Comment: Yes its the default messaging app....And yes the bubble pops up just for messages only....What I did is i went to App Info of this messaging app and disabled it....but since then i'm not getting any messages too :( .... pls suggest me a good messaging app.   thanks....

Comment: You can try google messenger https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging&hl=en

Comment: Ah..this is the icon of the default messaging app on my phone

Comment: Google messenger does not provide sms pop up. There may be some other app to provide sms pop up. May be a screen shot would be helpful.

Comment: I found it..it was iFloat SMS app....I just went to Settings->Apps->and Disabled it....let's see if it pops up Sameer so much for so quick turnaround..One more thing I wud lie to ask you pls reg up-gradation to Lollipop Version..I just purchased it on ys that it;s Upgradable to Lollipop....so can u pls guide me how and when can I upgrade it to Lollipop pls. thanks

Comment: I found it..it was iFloat SMS app....I just went to Settings->Apps->and Disabled it....let's see if it pops up Sameer so much for so quick turnaround..One more thing I wud lie to ask you pls reg up-gradation to Lollipop Version..I just purchased it on ys that it;s Upgradable to Lollipop....so can u pls guide me how and when can I upgrade it to Lollipop pls. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Disabling Notifications.

- Go to messaging app information.
- Uncheck **show notifications**.